$f(x) = x e^x$. Let $L : (0, \infty) \to (0, \infty)$ be its inverse function. Which of the following statements is correct?
Consider the function $f : (0, \infty) \to (0, \infty)$ given by $f(x) = x e^x$. Let $L : (0, \infty) \to (0, \infty)$ be its inverse function. Which of the following statements is correct?

$\lim_{x \to \infty}$ $\frac{L(x)}{\log x} = 1.$

$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{L(x)}{(\log x)^2} = 1.$

$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{L(x)}{\sqrt{\log x}} = 1.$

None of the remaining three options is correct.




I am unable to explicitly determine $L(x)$, the inverse of $f(x) = xe^x$. Hence, the remaining task is to approximate $L(x)$ asymptotically and analyse its growth in relation to functions of $\log x$ to resolve the given limits.

The answer is 1, according to Wolfram Alpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ProductLog%28x%29%2Fln%28x%29%2C+as+x+-%3E+infinity

The inverse to $f$ is the Lambert W function, which has been given a special name since it is not invertible in terms of elementary functions.
Instead, note that as $\lim_{x \to \infty} xe^x = \infty$, any of the three limits holds if and only if they still hold when we precompose with $f$.
For example, the first one becomes
$$
\frac{L(f(x))}{\log{x} + x} = \frac{x}{\log x+x} = \frac{1}{(\log x)/x+1} \to 1
$$
and so must be the right one as commented by Colin.

Since $f$ is surjective, there is a $z\in(0,\infty)$ such that $x = f(z) = z e^z$. Then $L(x) = z$ and $\log x = z + \log z$. Since $f$ is also strictly monotonic,
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{L(x)}{\log x} = \lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} \frac{z}{z+\log z} = 1.
$$
